# Minimal master page failed to provision: could not find master page gallery

Tags: 2010, upgrade

When upgrading from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 we are getting this error for a site collection:

```
Minimal master page failed to provision: could not find master page gallery
```

When you navigate to the site collection it is asking you to pick a template. Once you pick a template it sends you to a security error. I am a site collection admin.

I found this [site](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/adawson/post/2011/04/18/error-during-sharepoint-2010-upgrade-minimal-master-page-failed-to-provision-could-not-find-master-page-gallery.aspx) that says you need to delete or complete the site before upgrading.  We cannot delete this site collection.  What do they mean by complete?

Is there any other way to fix this issue?

**Update**

Here is the error from Upgrade----error.log

```
powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [INFO] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: Provisioning minimal master page in site: 
Site Url: http://shp-1-ptemp/dealers/1378
[powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [WARNING] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: Minimal  master page failed to provision: could not find master page gallery.
[powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [INFO] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: Provisioning  V4 master page in site: 
Site Url: http://shp-1-ptemp/dealers/1378
[powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [WARNING] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: V4 master  page failed to provision: could not find master page gallery.
[powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [INFO] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: Setting  UIVersion metadata on existing default master page
[powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [WARNING] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: Could not  find master page gallery. Metadata on default.master not set.
[powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [INFO] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: Executing visual upgrade in site: 
Site Url: http://shp-1-ptemp/dealers/1378
[powershell] [PerWebUpgradeAction (4.0.10.0)] [WARNING] [6/9/2013 8:54:38 PM]: Visual   
Upgrade failed on site: 
Site Url: http://shp-1-ptemp/dealers/1378
```

We have two site collections (/dealers/1079 is the other one) that are getting this error. Both of the sites seem to be empty in 2010.

When running the `Test-SPContentDatabase` PowerShell command in our 2013 server (this is where we eventually want to go) we get this error:

[image]

These two errors don't seem to match, so I believe we need to fix both of them.

Where should I focus my attention?

Should I open a new thread for the Orphan site issue?

Are the two errors related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole problem was with two Orphaned sites.

- Content_2 and 5 have 1079
- Content_5 and 6 have 1378

We should have ran the Preupgradechecker one more time before going through the upgrade steps.  This would have shown us that we had orphaned sites.

To fix the issue I had to delete the two orphaned sites from WSS that were in Content_5 before moving on with the upgrade.

This [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priyo/archive/2010/09/10/removing-orphan-sites-from-sharepoint-2007.aspx) shows how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to navigate to the site collection settings page under /_layouts/settings.aspx. This page uses the system master page and chances are you will be able to navigate through the menus to check the master page set at the site collection level as well as try to navigate to the Master Page gallery. See if that helps.

I would also recommend checking the ULS logs during page load when you try to access the site home page. A great tool for displaying "real time" ULS messages is the Uls Viewer http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer

Comment: When I go to the settings page I get a 404 not found. The ULS error states:  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002. Any other ideas?

Comment: Was that in-place or database attach upgrade? You know you may be getting 404 on any elements like stylesheets etc. IIS logs and/or Fiddler would tell you exactly what is missing.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment.  I was removed as a site admin.  I am able to get to the settings page but there isn't much there. It looks like there is no data. I will update the question with more info.